# VBA code to adjust image size in PowerPoint 2016

Tags: vba, image-resizing, powerpoint-2016

I am in my first week of learning VBA, and I am looking for a VBA code that will help me resize and reposition pictures pasted into PowerPoint 2016.  The desired picture format details are below:

Size
 - Height = 3.39"
 - Width = 6.67"
 - Rotation = 0
 - Scale Height = 62%
 - Scale Width = 62%
 - Aspect Ratio = Locked
 - Relative to original picture size = true

Position
 - Horizontal position = 0
 - Top Left Corner
 - Vertical position = 2.06
 - Top Left Corner

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Below is the code that worked for me.  Thanks for the support.

```
Sub ResizeAll()
For Each tSlide In ActiveWindow.Presentation.Slides
    tSlide.Select
    With tSlide.Shapes.Item(1)
    'assume a blank slide with one image added only
        .Select
        .Height = 72 * 3.39
        .Width = 72 * 6.67
    'algin middle (Horizontal Center)
        .Left = 0
        .Top = ActivePresentation.PageSetup.SlideHeight / 3.25
    End With
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: While it's not necessary to remove both of the .Select statements, neither of them is necessary, and without them, your code will run more quickly.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so this macro will adjust the details of every picture within your powerpoint.

```
Sub AdjustImages()

    Dim curSlide As Slide
    Dim curShape As Shape

    For Each curSlide In ActivePresentation.Slides
        For Each curShape In curSlide.Shapes
            With curShape

                'size:
                ''1 inch = 72 points
                .Height = 72 * 3.39
                .Width = 72 * 6.67

                .ScaleHeight 0.62, msoTrue
                .ScaleWidth 0.62, msoTrue

                .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue


                'position:
                .Rotation = 0

                .Left = 0
                .Top = 2.06

                'Relative to original picture size = true

            End With
        Next curShape
    Next curSlide

End Sub
```

The only part of your question that I don't really understand is when you mention it being "relative to original picture size = true". I can't seem to find an attribute that matches that.

Answer (score 0):

ub AdjustImages()

```
Dim curSlide As Slide
Dim curShape As Shape

For Each curSlide In ActivePresentation.Slides
    For Each curShape In curSlide.Shapes
        With curShape

            'size:
            ''1 inch = 72 points
            .Height = 72 * 3.39
            .Width = 72 * 6.67

            .ScaleHeight 0.62, msoTrue
            .ScaleWidth 0.62, msoTrue

            .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue


            'position:
            .Rotation = 0

            .Left = 0
            .Top = 2.06

            'Relative to original picture size = true

        End With
    Next curShape
Next curSlide
```

End Sub

Comment: How to do it for single image in each slides

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).